# ASP.NET vs creating/opening .HTML file in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, d3.js

I am currently attempting to import D3 (data driven documents) visualizations into Spotfire. My approach is to embed a web page into Spotfire, run the HTML and Javascript there, and then reference variables regarding the data tables, filtering and such from the SDK (C#).

I was wondering which approach would be better: making an ASP.NET project (which I have little experience with), or just creating an HTML file from inside a standard C# project, making a filestream, writing all the Javascript and HTML into the HTML file and then opening it.

However, when someone changes the filtering properties in Spotfire, I would need to reflect that by updating the Javascript to pass in different variables into D3. I'm not sure if this makes one of the approaches impossible or not.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided in the question, it appears you are comfortable working in Javascript. Why not give node.js + Express.js a shot?  If the code needs to be run locally you could pair it with appJS as well.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I am understanding my own task on a basic level. If I were to set the application's webbrowser.documenttext to giant block of HTML (which would reference a javascript file that I have), how would I get the javascript to reference back to the C# to use the filtering/marking schemes that the user has currently selected?

Ex. the user selects "day" as the filtering scheme. I would then need to use the C# and pass the changed filtering scheme to D3  so that the visualization changes. I'm just not sure how to update the javascript without redrawing the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC can work for you as well.